# directx11 texture positioning

Tags: c++, textures, game-engine, directx-11

I'm fairly new to game programming and I'm working on a basic 2D game engine as a learning exercise.

Basically, I want to load information about a sprite and then display it.

Part of the information I want to load about the sprite is its starting position on screen.

However, I've been playing around with the position of a sprite and it isn't behaving how I thought it would.

Setting the position of the sprite to (0, 0) puts the centre of the sprite in the bottom-left corner, which is what I expect; but setting the position of the sprite to (640, 480), which is supposed to be the size of screen and the width and height of the viewport, puts it near the top-right corner with a fair gap between it and the edges of the window, whereas I thought it would place the centre of the sprite in the top-right corner.

So my question is: What actually defines the limits of the drawable area, and how does the sprite's position relate to the actual screen coordinates?

As a follow-up question: Eventually I want to make the game full screen with a resolution of 1080p; would this affect the positions of sprites on screen, forcing me to go back and change them?

EDIT:
I've done some experimenting and I've found that the top-right corner is at about (800, 600), which is considerably larger than (640, 480)

Comment: Might be this problem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it and this problem seems to have been solved in Direct10, the origin of the render target was changed from what this says: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308049(v=vs.85).aspx
The gap between the sprite and the edge of the screen is quite sizeable so I think there must be something else going on. (I'd include a screenshot but it won't let me yet)

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the issue was. My projection matrix was setting the boundary of the viewable area to (800, 600)